# How to determine how much disk-space postgresql 9.1 requires as temp_space to run a query?

Tags: postgresql

Given a query `q` to execute. Is there a way to determine how much disk-space postgresql will (or used) as `temporary_space` in order to execute it (during its execution) ?

I'm under `Ubuntu 12.0.4` with `postgresql 9.1`

Answer (score 2):

Knowing how much will be used is hard.  How much has been used, you there are logging options for that.

```
set log_temp_files=0;
set client_min_messages TO log;
select count(distinct x) from generate_series(1,10000000) x;
```

> LOG:  temporary file: path "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp25126.2", size 120127488.
>
> LOG:  temporary file: path "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp25126.1", size 140000000

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT ...` to see how much space your current query with current params take. But it may need different amounth of space for different input parameters or different data set.

Some examples where the temp files are used:

```
Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 6848kB
Buffers: shared hit=4428, temp read=2305 written=2305
```